# Failing to create table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE example 
(
ycode char(5) NOT NULL,
xcode char(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_EXAMPLE PRIMARY KEY (ycode,xcode),
CONSTRAINT FK_EXAMPLE_Y FOREIGN KEY (ycode) REFERENCES ycode(ycode),
CONSTRAINT FK_EXAMPLE_X FOREIGN KEY (xcode) REFERENCES xcode(xcode),
);
```

This is the script that I am using. It is followed up by the error

```
Server: Msg 1776, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'xcode'
that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_EXAMPLE_X'.
Server: Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

My X table has 5 fields but one of them is xcode as a primary key.

Comment: "My X table has 5 fields but one of them is xcode as a primary key." Are you certain of this? The error indicates this is not the case. Please format your SQL statement and also provide a schema for the xcode table.

Comment: You have a table called xcode with a column xcode and that column is a primary key? That does not seem correct.

Comment: CREATE TABLE X
(
xcode char(10) NOT NULL,
type char(2) NOT NULL,
title varchar(100) NULL,
cipdesc varchar(MAX) NULL,
titls varchar(35) NULL,
level char(1),
CONSTRAINT PK_X PRIMARY KEY (x, type),
CONSTRAINT FK_X_OCCTYPES FOREIGN KEY (type) REFERENCES occtypes(type),
);

This is the create script for the X table. xcode is the first field and is a primary key and character (10)

Comment: You have a table called X but you didn't reference it in your original code at all. This is why writing readable code is useful! :)

Comment: I work for a state government and so can't paste in the exact code. The create script for X is on line 475 and EXAMPLE is 2988. Not sure if that is relevant but it would seem as if there is some order to it.

Comment: Well either you obfuscated the data wrong or your database isn't what you think it is because you are referencing table "xcode" in your query but your table is "X". The problem is you are using the wrong table, not that there is no key in the table. There is no table xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a primary key in your secondary table you are attempting to join to.  Add a primary key to your table you are trying to join to and ensure that the data types are the same for the secondary table's type and the primary.

Example:

```
--Works
IF OBJECT_ID('.X') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE .X;
CREATE TABLE X (Id INT IDENTITY, YId INT, Val VARCHAR(8), CONSTRAINT PK_X_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id))

IF OBJECT_ID('.Y') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE .Y;
CREATE TABLE Y (Id INT IDENTITY, Val VARCHAR(8), CONSTRAINT PK_Y_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id))

ALTER TABLE dbo.X
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_X_Y_Id FOREIGN KEY(YId) REFERENCES Y(Id)

--Fails, due to Table Y not having appropriate Primary Key
IF OBJECT_ID('.X') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE .X;
CREATE TABLE X (Id INT IDENTITY, YId INT, Val VARCHAR(8), CONSTRAINT PK_X_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id))

IF OBJECT_ID('.Y') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE .Y;
CREATE TABLE Y (Id INT IDENTITY, Val VARCHAR(8))

ALTER TABLE dbo.X
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_X_Y_Id FOREIGN KEY(YId) REFERENCES Y(Id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue ended up being that the foreign key in my secondary table was not the same as that of the primary table. Its convoluted but your example led to the solution indirectly.

Comment: No problem, if you are happy with the answer mark it complete.